# Average Score of all ratings in comments

Tags: comments, rating, review

i have a rating system in comments, for each comment user can rate 1-5 Stars.

Now , i want the average of all ratings in comments of that post to show.

How can i do that.

Here is the link to the code file related to My rating System. Current Users can rate and comment. But i want the average of all comment ratings in that post. And this is a custom Post type.

check this link for the code related to rating used in the site.

http://pastebin.com/LcRyjSPK

Comment: What should i write in <li> </li> to create tab called My Reviews and in that tab show users comments with Post title

Comment: what's the output of average ratings you are getting now?

Comment: i dont have an average function added to single-places.php, currently only people/users can comment with their rating. and the above pastebin page is the code for all the rating function. now i want to create a function to call to give me the average of all comment rations in a post to show.

Comment: first of all wrap your table creation/checking code in a function and hook into plugin activation hook, this will save some resources.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

add this code into your plugin file to register activation hook

```
// register activation hook
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_rating_plugin_activation' );
```

now create a function and add your table creation code into

```
function my_rating_plugin_activation() {
    global $wpdb, $rating_table_name;
    if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE \"$rating_table_name\"") != $rating_table_name) {
        $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $rating_table_name (
            rating_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            rating_postid int(11) NOT NULL,
            rating_posttitle text NOT NULL,
            rating_rating int(2) NOT NULL,
            rating_timestamp varchar(15) NOT NULL,
            rating_ip varchar(40) NOT NULL,
            rating_host varchar(200) NOT NULL,
            rating_username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            rating_userid int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            comment_id int(11) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (rating_id)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM");
    }
}
```

Comment: shall i add this function directly into the code i have provided. or do i need to delete some code from the existing template and add this one somewher

Comment: i added the above code at the end of the template before ?>

Comment: add activation hook and function by replacing table creation code from plugin and place it at same place where the table creation code is.

Comment: i did that, but how will i get to show the average of all comment ratings

Comment: Can you see the code around Line no 69 which says get average ratings. can you modify that and call the function to display average ratings