# How to display Custom Taxonomy of Custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created Custom Post type called "places"

For that I created Custom Taxonomy Category called "Music".

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_music' );

function register_taxonomy_music() {

$labels = array( 
    'name' => _x( 'Music', 'music' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Music', 'music' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Search Music', 'music' ),
    'popular_items' => _x( 'Popular Music', 'music' ),
    'all_items' => _x( 'All Music', 'music' ),
    'parent_item' => _x( 'Parent Music', 'music' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Music:', 'music' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Music', 'music' ),
    'update_item' => _x( 'Update Music', 'music' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Music', 'music' ),
    'new_item_name' => _x( 'New Music', 'music' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => _x( 'Separate music with commas', 'music' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => _x( 'Add or remove music', 'music' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => _x( 'Choose from the most used music', 'music' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Music', 'music' ),
);

$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,

    'rewrite' => true,
    'query_var' => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'music', array('places'), $args );
}
```

Now, I want to display the categories in `single-places.php`.

How can I display the categories "Music".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get terms in single post type template by using `wp_get_post_terms();` inside loop

```
<?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'music');
if ($terms) {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $out[] = '<a class="' .$term->slug .'" href="' .get_term_link( $term->slug, 'music') .'">' .$term->name .'</a>';
    }
    echo join( ', ', $out );
} ?>
```

Comment: After the query, i get Music: Rock, Jazz, House, ....              I want to add icons in front of the Rock, Jazz etc, can you create classes for each value like rock, jazz so that i can add icons in front of the categories

Comment: can you please create classes for each categories and give so that i can add icons

Comment: ok edited my answer and added term slug as css class now you can style each term as you wish.

Comment: can you add a comma next to each term slug, currently all the terms are next to each other without gap.

Comment: ok edited now it will output terms separate by commas if more then 1

Comment: thank you. can you please help me in this Question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113215/average-score-of-all-ratings-in-comments

Comment: Please fix this its like this (1) Place: Chicago (2) Music: Chicago, Rock, Jazz (3) Food: Chicago, Rock, Jazz , Chinese, Thai, Italian It is first showing previous fields then that category everytime

Comment: edited and fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer of @Anjum works perfectly, it can be done also using `get_the_terms()`, a function that get the terms using `wp_get_post_terms()` or `get_object_term_cache()`, depend of the situation. So using `get_the_terms()` can be more appropiate if you don't need to pass extra arguments, as it is the case.

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'music');
if ($terms) {
     foreach ($terms as $term) {
     $out[] = '<a class="' .$term->slug .'" href="' .get_term_link( $term->slug, 'music') .'">' .$term->name .'</a>';
  }
    echo join( ', ', $out );
}
?>
```

References:

1. [get_the_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)
2. [wp_get_post_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)

Comment: its repeating each category into next categories

Comment: its like this (1) Place: Chicago (2) Music: Chicago, Rock, Jazz (3) Food: Chicago, Rock, Jazz , Chinese, Thai, Italian   It is first showing previous fields then that category everytime

Comment: In your question you say "I created Custom Taxonomy Category called "Music"......How can I display the categories "Music"?" and that is what this code does, and it does using a better function that the accepted answer (I think, read the reasons in my answer). If your question has changed, please edit it or start new one.

Comment: Can you post the code that your are currently using?